# Is it possible to get crc32 of the end of file if I know crc32 of the beginning and of the whole file?

Tags: crc32

Suppose I have a file split into parts: f = (p1, p2). I have calculated crc32(p1) and crc32(f). Is there a simple way to calculate crc32(p2)?

I'm mostly interested in solutions with complexity O(1), but O(n) will do, where n = length(p1) (suppose length(p1) is much less then length(p2)).

The main idea is not to iterate through the second part of file.

Comment: As a simplifying assumption, are we allowed to assume that `len(p1)%4==0`?

Comment: It isn't true for initial problem, but I'm interested in solution for len(p1)%4==0 if no other solution comes.

Comment: Since you have CRC32(p1), I'm guessing you mean that the solution can be O(n), where n = length(p2), right? By the way, I don't think O(1) is possible unless the length(p2) is fixed.

Comment: No, I mean complexity O(n) when n = length(p1). Solution with complexity O(length(p2)) is obvious: CRC32(p2).

Comment: As for O(1), it would be possible in case CRC32 was a linear algoritm as CRC in general is (wthout INITXOR and FINALXOR). (Saying "linear" I mean crc32(a) XOR crc32(b) = crc32(a XOR b)).

Comment: CRC32 is linear just like all CRCs. And you don't need to compute CRC32(p2) if you have CRC32(p1) and CRC32(f). The complexity O(n) for n = length(p2) is necessary because you need to compute the remainder of (CRC32(p1) << length(p2)) / G32(X), where G32(X) is the polynomial used for CRC32. So, you don't need the actual data to compute CRC32(p2)

Comment: On the other hand, if you use table lookup, you can definitely have an O(1) solution, BUT your table size is not practical... :)